# Move table row to a new table

Tags: sql, sqlite

In SQLite is it possible to move a whole row of a table to another table in one query, rather than selecting the row then inserting it into another table then deleting the row in the original table (3 query's)

Answer (score 0):

well i am not sure about doing all 3 in one query but you can do the below for select and insert

Select column1, column2 into tableName

and then your delete